# Copying named range from Excel to a specific location in a Word document without using bookmarks

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a series of ranges in Excel.

Example:

| table key | table range |
| --- | --- |
| table6 | A4:G14 |
| table7 | A15:G20 |
| table8 | A21:E30 |

and so on.

How can I search a Word document for the names in column 1 and paste the ranges in the second column?

This is the segment of the code I have

```vb
For Each cell In rng "rng is the range of the table key column"
    If cell.Value = "" Then Exit For
    With wdDoc.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Text = cell.Value
        .Replacement.Text = Range(cell.Offset(0, 1))
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next
```

I get an error in the `replacement.text` line but I don't know how to replace it with a range.

---

I also tried the code below to copy and paste the ranges in the table but I get an object defined error at the pasteexceltable line:

```vb
Set appWd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
set wdFind = appWd.Selection.Find
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "" Then Exit For
    ClipT = " "
    Range(cell.Offset(0, 1)).Copy
    wdFind.Text = cell.Value
    wdFind.Replacement.Text = ""
    wdFind.Forward = True
    wdFind.Wrap = wdFindContinue
    wdFind.Execute
    Call CheckClipBrd 'This function checks if the clipboard is empty'
    Range(cell.Offset(0, 1)).Copy
    ActiveWindow.Selection.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=False, _
        RTF:=True
    CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: adding 'cell.Offset(0, 1).Value'  will only add the text of the second column. I want it to add the range stated in that column. I can't be explicit as the ranges change continuously, so I don't want to keep changing it. I have a segment of code that gets me the address of each range. All that's left is being able to paste that range.

Comment: Ah. I see. `Range(cell.Offset(0, 1))` is a 2D array if it refers to a multi-cell range. You can't assign a 2D array to the `.Replacement.Text`. Copy/paste maybe?

Comment: @BigBen I edited the post to display a code i tried to run to copy and paste the range. the code does everything as desired but fails when I try to execute the paste line at the end

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73518708/plain-text-being-pasted-instead-of-table/73518983#73518983

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, your Word template contains the relevant tables and each is bookmarked with the same name as the table names in Excel, then, provided each Word table:

• has both a header row and an empty data row; and

• the same number of columns as your Excel data,

you could use code like:

```
Sub ExportToWord()
' Note: A reference to the Microsoft Word # Object Library is required,
' set via Tools|References in the Excel VBE.
Dim WdApp As New Word.Application, WdDoc As Word.Document
Dim XlSht As Excel.Worksheet, XlTbl As Excel.ListObject
Set XlSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With WdApp
  Set WdDoc = .Documents.Add(Template:="full name & path to template")
  For Each XlTbl In XlSht.ListObjects
    XlTbl.DataBodyRange.Copy
    With WdDoc
      If .Bookmarks.Exists(XlTbl.Name) Then
        With .Bookmarks.Exists(XlTbl.Name)
          .Range.PasteAppendTable
          .Rows(2).Delete
        End With
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

The reason for the Word table initially having an empty data row is so that the paste doesn't take on the formatting of the header row.

If you really, really don't want to use bookmarks, you would need another way of correlating the Word tables and Excel data (e.g. via Find for an identifying string [such as the Excel table's name] in Word, or by the Word table index # [which might be retrieved from the Excel table's name]).

For example, if the Excel table's name is in the Word table's second row:

```
Sub ExportToWord()
' Note: A reference to the Microsoft Word # Object Library is required,
' set via Tools|References in the Excel VBE.
Dim WdApp As New Word.Application, WdDoc As Word.Document
Dim XlSht As Excel.Worksheet, XlTbl As Excel.ListObject
Set XlSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With WdApp
  Set WdDoc = .Documents.Add(Template:="full name & path to template")
  For Each XlTbl In XlSht.ListObjects
    XlTbl.DataBodyRange.Copy
    With WdDoc
      With .Range.
        With .Find
          .Text = XlTbl.Name
          .MatchWildcards = True
          .Execute
        End With
        If .Find.Found = True Then
          With .Tables(1)
            .Range.PasteAppendTable
            .Rows(2).Delete
          End With
        End If
      End With
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

or, if the the Word table's index # corresponds with the Excel table's name:

```
Sub ExportToWord()
' Note: A reference to the Microsoft Word # Object Library is required,
' set via Tools|References in the Excel VBE.
Dim WdApp As New Word.Application, WdDoc As Word.Document
Dim XlSht As Excel.Worksheet, XlTbl As Excel.ListObject
Set XlSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With WdApp
  Set WdDoc = .Documents.Add(Template:="full name & path to template")
  For Each XlTbl In XlSht.ListObjects
    XlTbl.DataBodyRange.Copy
    With WdDoc
        With .Tables(Replace(XlTbl.Name, "Table", ""))
          .Range.PasteAppendTable
          .Rows(2).Delete
        End With
      End If
    End With
  Next
End With
End Sub
```